# azure app service with docker image is initialized correctly but admin login page is not loading

Tags: docker, azure-appservice

I have a keycloak docker image from an external party in an app service running.

The docker image seems loading fine:

[image]

but when I click on the "administration console" link which is is:

```
https://my-test-keycloak.azurewebsites.net/auth/admin/
```

then I get blank white screen in the browser with a 404 Error about this:

```
https://host.docker.internal/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/3p-cookies/step1.html?version=5f8ww
```

Why is my admin console not loading?

These are my app settings in the app service which get injected into docker image as ENV variables:

```
{
    "name": "KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT",
    "value": "true",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS",
    "value": "true",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "KC_HTTP_ENABLED",
    "value": "true",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH",
    "value": "/auth/", // tried also "/auth"
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "KC_PROXY",
    "value": "passthrough", // tried also "edge"
    "slotSetting": false
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the admin console is trying to reference host.docker.internal, which is wrong.

Ensure that Keycloak is configured with the correct base URL. If you don't explicitly set it, Keycloak might guess the wrong one. You can try setting the KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL to your actual base URL:

```json
{
    "name": "KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL",
    "value": "https://my-test-keycloak.azurewebsites.net/auth",
    "slotSetting": false
}
```

Also if you have access to the Dockerfile or the image's internals, ensure that there aren't any hardcoded references to host.docker.internal or any other hostname. This could be overriding your environment variables.

I will also recommend to increase the logging level for Keycloak to get more detailed logs. This might give you hints about what's going wrong. You might need to add the KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL env variable and set it to DEBUG.

Comment: When I use your configuration then nothing changes. The 404 url is still the same!

Comment: this: host.docker.internal is the KC_HOSTNAME. When I remove it the docker image does not get initialized. So I need that one. But there is the KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN but that did not help either. I guess this is my problem: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/11170  port 8080 is exposed in docker but when I use WEBSITE_PORT 8443 which is injected into docker run expose 8443 then the container can not be pinged anymore and the container is stopped!